# Static Member issue in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have faced a problem while i was trying to code an app using Android studio, for calculating a special kind of GPAs, actually it's medical students GPA in my country.

which is as follow  :

```
   '
public class MainPage extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText smle,cv,gpa;
TextView ans;

Double s,c,g,sum;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);
    smle=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.smle);
    cv=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.cv);
    gpa=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.gpa);
  TextView  ans=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ans);
// here it says that the variable "ans" is never used. 
    s=Double.parseDouble(smle.getText().toString());
    c=Double.parseDouble(cv.getText().toString());
    g=Double.parseDouble(gpa.getText().toString());



}
public void onCal(View view)
{

    sum=(g*20*0.30)+c+(s*0.50);
//Here it says static member 'java.lang.String.valueOf(java.lang.Object) is accessed via instance reference  
    ans.setText(toString().valueOf(ans));
```

'
what should I do to fix this issue?

I'm sorry for posting the hall thing,but I'm in my early steps in coding .

Answer (score 2):

You declare `ans` twice. Once as an instance variable (third line) then again in onCreate(). Replace

```
TextView  ans=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ans);
```

with

```
ans=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ans);
```

in onCreate() so you assign to the ans variable that is visible to the entire object.